# Redis get returning true in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis

I'm writing a RESTful API in typescript and I'm trying to use my already parsed data that is stored in redis with a specific key in another function. The problem I am having is that instead of receiving the actual data from redis, I just keep receiving a boolean value of true. I have tried googling a lot and reading the redis documentation, unfortunately to no avail. Does anyone here now how I can access the actual data so I can use it in another function? I suspect I am facing some kind of async problems here, but I am not entirely sure.

For example if I try to bind the response to a variable this will happen:

```
const key = something
const reply = client.mget(key);
console.log("This is the reply: " + reply);

This is the reply: true
```

Br,
Victor

EDIT:

So basically I'm sending the data from https.get into an object handler, which parses the data into my preferred form and then I stringify that object and send it into redis as a string, which looks like this:

```
client.set(redisInfo, JSON.stringify(objecthandler(newdata)));
```

My actual code for getting the data at the moment looks like this:

```
const getRedis = (rediskey: string, success: any, error: any) => {
    client.mget(rediskey, function (err: Error, reply: any) {
        if (!err) {
            success(reply);
        }
        else {
            error(err);
        }
    });
};

//My callback function that I'm trying to get to work so I can use the redis data in other functions
function getrediscallback(key: string) {
       getRedis(key, function success(reply: string): string {
       //This console.log actually returns the data that I want
        console.log("this is the reply: " + reply);
            return reply;
            },
function error(err: Error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong" + err);
});
}
```

So when I use the callback in another function, it will look something like this:

```
const redisdata = getrediscallback("getCars");
//This gives me the value of undefined
console.log(redisdata)
```

This means that the callback function actually gets the actual data, but it is never reached later on when I use the callback function in another function.

Comment: please write code for insert into redis. so anyone can check and let you know if there is something wrong or not

Comment: which client library do you use for redis? is that mget method sync?

Comment: Need more info about what value you're setting to the key? Which client library you're using?

Comment: I added more information that should (hopefully) answer your questions, thanks!

Comment: instead of mget use only ".get" method.

Comment: I'm not sure what your callback is supposed to be doing; your `return reply` is returning from the callback function, not `getrediscallback`. I think you need to get a better handle on how callbacks in general work, e.g., generalized async programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient(6379);

const bluebird = require("bluebird");

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);

bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);

const redisdata = await client.getAsync('user:photos');

if (redisdata) {
  console.log(`cache EXISTS`)
  return res.json({ source: 'cache', data: JSON.parse(redisdata) })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide some explanation for your code? Code should appear in a code block surrounded by backticks. Here's where you can find more information about formatting your answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)).

Answer (score 0):

```
 import util from "util";
 import redisClient from "../config/redisConfig";
 let hgetall = util.promisify(redisClient.hgetall).bind(redisClient);
 await hgetall("Key")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.